# How to automate migration script generation for a couple of microservice databases in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, docker, terminal, mariadb, github-actions

We use MariaDB docker for local development and since we're using microservice architecture, we have many databases. For example for a typical application, we might have 20 databases.

And we also use MariaDB docker for the production environment.

I'm trying to make a GitHub action to automate database migration script generation. This is what the action does:

1. Runs each night, or on-demand
2. Pull our code from GitHub
3. Pull MariaDB from docker hub
4. Builds our databases in the docker
5. Compares those databases, to our production databases // this part I'm stuck in

I'm stuck in comapring databases via command line. in SQL Server, there is this `SqlPackage.exe` that is a free command-line utility that can be used to automate migration script generation in CI/CD pipelines.

How can I achieve something similar for MariaDB?

I want to be able to create migration scripts from command-line, inside GitHub actions.

Comment: Are you looking for an existing tool to accomplish this task or are you prepared to create your own tool? The former is explicitly off topic here on SO, the latter can be on topic, if you can ask a specific enough question.

Comment: @Shadow, why the former is off-topic? I want to create migrations scripts in my CI/CD pipeline. I just want to somehow do it. If there is a tool that does it, I would welcome it. If I need to build it myself, I would build it. I don't know.

Comment: @Shadow, why the former is off-topic? I want to create migrations scripts in my CI/CD pipeline. I just want to somehow do it. If there is a tool that does it, I would welcome it. If I need to build it myself, I would build it. I don't know.

Comment: Pls read the 3rd numbered point on what's considered off topuc and why in SO's help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic If you are not familiar with what questions you can ask on SO, then I suggest you to consult the guidance before asking a question! Btw, the answer that was removed from this question deminstrates perfectly why asking for product recommendatiins are explicitly off topic here on SO...

Comment: It looks like rather than 5, you should have "run the test suite of our code against built/migrated database". I suspect this would catch significantly more problems reliably than a database comparison. As a mariadb test service container I could be biased (I built it) and suggest [quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:{major version}](https://mariadb.org/new-service-quay-io-mariadb-foundation-mariadb-devel/). As a non-dockerhub service there aren't rate limits.